# PHP: Global keyword not working after POST request

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli, global-variables

I've an PHP form for users to edit personal details. For certain reason, I will need to know **which value has been modified** by the users instead of overwriting all details to the database. Once the page is loaded, the *else statement* will first be executed to fetch content from database and display it on the page. Once the submit button of the form is clicked, the *if statement* will be executed.

```
<?php
$everywhere = [];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //once the submit button is clicked, collect all the values from the form
    $edited = [];
    $edited['Name']= ...;
    $edited['Address'] = ...;


    //error 
    //$everywhere becomes undefined 
    global $everywhere;
    foreach($everywhere as $x=>$x_val){
        echo "<h2>".$x."=".$x_val." "."</h2>";
    }
    
    
}else{ 
    //sqli_ query line
    //sqli_fetch_assoc line
    
    //original personal details will be stored into $items
    $items = [];
    $items['Name'] = ...;
    $items['Address'] = ...;
    
    global $everywhere;
    $everywhere = $items;
}

?>

<!--display original personal details-->
<form method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>Name</dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $items['user_name']; ?>"/></dd>
    </dl>
    ......
    ......

    <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

I plan to compare the `$everywhere` and `$edited` in the *if statement* so that I get to know which value has been modified. But `$everywhere` has become undefined in the *if statement*. Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake of `$everywhere` in the if statement, and another in the else statement.

```
...
    global $everywhere;
    foreach(**$everywhere** as $x=>$x_val){
        echo "<h2>".$x."=".$x_val." "."</h2>";
    }
...
    global **$everywhere**;
    $everywhere = $items;
}

?>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I've updated the question. But it still couldn't work without spelling mistake.

Comment: Have you tried without the `global $everywhere;` lines? The `global` keyword is only required if the variable is in a user-defined function. In PHP, it is not required if simply within an if statement code block. The If code block is in the same scope as outside that code block where you define `$everything`.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. I know that the problem can be solved if I fetch the content from the database again inside the *if statement* but I wonder if there is a smarter way of solving it. So that users don't have to keep sending requests to the server

Comment: Once the user hits Submit, $everywhere will not contain the data given to it by the line `$everywhere = $items;`. One solution is you could create hidden input fields containing the original database content, which would then be passed through as form data, and it could be checked in PHP.

Comment: I solved the problem with another way but I agree that the solution that you mentioned is viable too. Thank you